# Mongoose Types.Array throwing error while saving new document - Typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

```
export interface User {
  roles: mongoose.Types.Array<string>,
}

/* user schema */
const schema = new mongoose.Schema<User>({
   roles: {type: [String], required: true}
})

const Users = mongoose.model<User>("user", schema);
```

now if I fetch a document with `find`, I do get mongoose Array specific IntelliSense for `roles` array ($push, $pop, $addToSet, etc.

But while saving a new document, typescript complains that roles Array `is missing the following properties from type 'Array<string>': $pop, $shift, addToSet, isMongooseArray, and 5 more.`

```
const newUser: User = { roles: ['abc','xyz'] }
new Users(newUser).save();
```

I can do a one-liner `save` like this:

```
new Users({roles: ['abc,xyz']).save();
```

and the error would go away. But I completely loose out on code-completion while saving a new document. How to make TS suppress warning while saving a new document having arrays without `$push, $pop etc` properties?

Comment: Its fine saving for document, but I loose out on intellisense for documents fetched with `find`

Comment: You are saying with that change, when you are trying do to `Users.find({ roles: { $in: ['abc'] } })` or similar, you get errors from TypeScript?

Comment: Or are you saying that the documents when you iterate over them don’t have array properties? Maybe update your question to show the query you are doing and what operations you are trying to do on the results.

Comment: For instance, If I fetch a document, `const userFound = Users.findOne({...})`, `userFound.roles.$pop` would be undefined according to TS (If I go for `string[]`), but it (`$pop`) does exists.

Comment: Not sure who you mean by doing `userFound.roles.$pop`. Operator `$pop` would be used in operations like `updateOne`. For something like `push`, you can simply do `userFound.roles.push('whatever')`, as in treat it like a normal array then save after, per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype) (look at array example). You seem to be referring to [update statements](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) such as $set, $push, etc.

Comment: MongoDb Array update operators? Like $pop : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/

Comment: Yes, those are operators that you use in the second argument of [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne) and similar. That's not on actual document objects directly. Can you show an example from docs/site where $push or $pop is being applied directly to a mongoose object returned from a query? I just may have never seen that which is causing my confusion.

Comment: You can use these operators on a Mongoose Array (returned by a query): https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray Like in my case, `userFound.roles.addToSet('abc123')` works perfectly fine.

Comment: I see what you are saying, thanks for sharing that doc, if you keep your original interface and do `const newUser = new Users({ roles: ['abc','xyz'] });`, then can you do `newUser.roles. addToSet('abc123'); newUser.save()`?

Comment: It should probably work, `(newUser.roles.push works)` you can get a better insight here : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/schemas.html#arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
import {AnyKeys, AnyObject} from "mongoose";

type BaseDoc<T> = AnyKeys<T> & AnyObject;
```

Using BaseDoc would suppress the TS warning while defining an object.

```
const newUser: BaseDoc<User> = { roles: ['abc','xyz'] }
```

and the documents returned by a query will also have intellisense for mongoose array operators.